# Hide thumbnails in jssor silder

Tags: jssor

I am using jssor slider .I have a requirement, I used images gallery with thumbnails . When clicked on external button thumbnails should hide and image should align centre in slider and arrows should align left and right to slider.

If you know how to set slider height and width according to window size please help me.

Comment: What have you done so far, or found online?

Answer (score 0):

Your slider is made of 'outer container', 'slides' container and 'thumbnail navigator' container. You can adjust layout dynamically.

Refefence: http://www.jssor.com/development/tip-arrange-layout-adjust-size.html

You can scale the slider while window resizes, please note that jssor slider always keeps aspect ratio.
Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/tip-make-responsive-slider.html